# Position fixed with vh not working properly on chrome, any assitance?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, css-position, viewport-units

I'm having a problem, specifically when I use chrome. I use on my website portfolio a modal element, when users click on it, the modal's background appears only in the upper page taking the whole width. Well I use a 100vh on the modal's bg and set it as position:fixed, and align the modal's content in the center (flex). It works normally in other browsers but not on chrome.
Here's a code snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-bg">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="img-box">
            <img src="">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>Some Text here</p>
            <div class="btns">
                <a href="#">btn-1</a>
                <a href="#>btn-2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a SCSS Snippet:

```
.modal-bg {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in;

    .box-container {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        width: 80%;
        height: 60rem;
        max-width: 82rem;
        min-height: 45rem;
        border-radius: 32px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        overflow: hidden;

        .img-box {
            margin: 0 .8rem;
            height: 50%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            
            img {
                max-width: 53rem;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        .caption {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            justify-self: flex-end;
            font-size: 1.8rem;
            color: #000000;
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 2rem;
            background-color: #ffffff;

            .btns {
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-around;
                align-items: center;
                margin: 1rem 0;
                
                a {
                    line-height: 2.4rem;
                    color: black;
                    font-size: 1.4rem;
                    display: flex;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    padding: .8rem;
                    background-color: #ffffff;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your `.modal-bg` covers the whole height of the screen just fine for me in Chrome on Windows with the code you've given, testing in CodePen, though obviously it's invisible because you have `visibility: hidden; opacity: 0`. But assuming the visibility/opacity isn't the issue, I'd say you need to update your question with a larger code snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks For your answer and time! Well it's a problem on my portfolio website. Here is the link www.iamshour.com

Comment: The problem appears in the frontend section, when you hover over a window there, an image appears, and when you click on it, the modal shows. Its working perfectly fine on my HUAWEI browser on my phone, but the problem happens on chrome (both phone and desktop)

Comment: I didn't take the time to figure out the whole deal, but it looks like you have a selector `:not(.btn:hover)` that is applying `transform: translate(0, 0)` and when that is commented out everything works as expected. Probably this is because transforms create new painting layers, and that can have weird consequences with positioning sometimes. You probably want a selector more like `.btn:not(:hover)` that will only apply to the buttons. The selector, as you have it, applies to damn near every element in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for heads up man ❤️❤️ I'll definitely check it out.